# Is there an AWS equivalent to `Stackdriver Sinks to BigQuery`

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, amazon-cloudwatch, stackdriver

I use a lot StackDriver sinks to BigQuery. It helps on keeping the Data and have them in a convenient queryable form.
I am searching for the equivalent on AWS using CloudWatch but it seems only S3 is integrated. Any workarounds or should I code it?

Comment: You may have a look at [BigQuery schema for Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery)

Comment: Is it possible for your use case to collect data at AWS and put it into Cloud Operations (Stackdriver) to analyze it at BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a workaround. It needs only one code component reading from S3 and posting to Stackdriver, then GCP sinks can pickup.

Create a CloudWatch Sink to S3 bucket.

The S3 bucket will be integrated to send SNS messages on object Creation.

A process should listen to those SNS notifications and copy the contents of the bucket into StackDriver.

Since the guarantees of SNS and Cloudwatch to S3 are there, a Lambda function on the SNS notification messages can make the solution more seamless.